# Use a variable inside a dictionary (associative array) in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have this particular script which uses a javascript dictonary

```
var z= 'Bingo';
var fruit={ 'Bingo' :1};
var fruit2={ z :1};
alert(fruit[z]);
alert(fruit2[z]);
alert(fruit2['z']);
```

The first alert gives the expected value 1. However, the second alert gives the alert value as "undefined" and third alert gives the output as 1. Is there a way to use a variable inside a dictionary, ie. can we specify the javascript interpreter to read z as a variable rather than as string 'z'?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an extremely basic feature which is covered in the first pages of any tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this easily, but not inside an object literal. Property names in object literals are taken literally. They are not variable names. JavaScript quotes them implicitly if you don't quote them.

For example, these two object literals are the same:

```
{ a: 1 }

{ 'a': 1 }
```

To use a variable, you need to use `[]` notation outside an object literal:

```
var z = 'Bingo';
var fruit2 = {};
fruit2[z] = 1;
```

Comment: Explain how you can't do it inside an object literal please.

Comment: Actually, I have a huge dictionary which needs to be created. The above method will be a cumbersome job to do, I am looking for an approach if I can use the variable inside the inline definition of the dictionary.

Comment: You can't do that. You have to use `[]` notation if you want to use variable names instead of literal property names.

Comment: Ah.  I understand the question and the answer now.  Thanks. +1

Comment: @AbhinavJain This approach shouldn't be much more cumbersome.

Comment: Seems I will have to proceed this way only. Thanks for the help! :)